# Silverlight: Make all descendants of an element have a margin?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Is there a way in Silverlight 4 to dictate that all elements within a `StackPanel` must have a margin, instead of specifying `margin="10,0"` on each one?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it's not possible declaratively in XAML with the `StackPanel` directly. It's the conceptual philosophy in Silverlight/WPF that a panel should not modify properties of its children. So you could implement your own Panel that does so anyway, or you could use an `ItemsControl` like that:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Margin="10,0" Content="{Binding Content}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    [...]

</ItemsControl>
```

An `ItemsControl` uses a `StackPanel` by default, you can use its `ItemsPanel` property to define another Panel as an `ItemsPanelTemplate` if you wish so.

Comment: You can also ensure the ItemsControl behaves like a StackPanel by specifying its `ItemsPanel` to be a StackPanel. Although that is likely the default. At least this way you can control Orientation.

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd do it is by defining implicit styles in the StackPanel's resources, for each control type that will be used within the StackPanel.  To save defining the value repeatedly for each control type, you can create a named base style that targets FrameworkElement and defines the style(s), from which the style for each control type can inherit.  An example is below:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CommonStyle" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonStyle}" />
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonStyle}" />
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonStyle}" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <Button>Button</Button>
    <TextBlock Text="Text" />
    <CheckBox>Check Box</CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Note how each control in the StackPanel will have the margin applied, without needing to define it on each control.

Hope this helps...

Chris Anderson

PS. Blatant self promotion - this is based upon the inheritance trick in my book [Pro Business Applications with Silverlight 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430272074) :).

Answer (score 0):

Put your stackpanel within a Border element and set the Border Padding to "10 0"

Comment: Why is the Border necessary when StackPanel has a Margin property? This also doesn't account for placing margin between each child, which the OP probably wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this programmatically; your StackPanel has a Children collection. You could use this to iterate through them and set the margin.